# Returning List<T> of instantiated classes from IOC

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm looking into using a IOC container but I'm working with legacy code and there are loads of `CreateInstance`'s everywhere and then things done with that class.

Is there a way I can get a IOC container to return a list of classes it has instantiated so the methods currently in use can continue doing their thing just without the `CreateInstance`

For example Autofac will scan an assembly/set of assemblies with code similar to the below, I was just wondering if it can return a `List<T>` of the classes it has created.

```
var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

**UPDATE:** I'm just deciding on which IOC to use but need the above functionality to tell me at what classes have been instantiated.

Comment: could you please post some code?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You already have an IOC and you want to know at run time what it has instantiated, or you want to replace some existing implementation with IOC?  Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like

```
var classes = _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<YourClassType>>().ToList();
```

The above syntax works as long as all classes that derive `YourClassType` has been been registered as it.

`_container.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>()` tells autofac to resolve all classes that implement `T`.

Comment: Can T be a base type? If I have a lot of classes that inherit off one class can I specify the base class?

Answer (score 1):

One of the tags says u are using Autofac. So i believe that u have access to the IContainer. Autofac tracks the instances of every object it creates. Look at the scope it has. For more information read the documentation http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances

I found a good blog about Autofac, maybe u can read about it for understanding LifeTimeScopes etc
http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/